# File Upload Limitation on Google Cloud Run

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, spdy

We deployed a node application on cloud run and it is working fine. Now we have got a new requirement of uploading files of size **Up to 5GB** and for some business reasons we won’t be able to use cloud storage. After some initial research we found that **cloud run has limit of 32MB** and this limit is only for HTTP1 requests but not HTTP2 requests. You can find that in below URL.

https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas#cloud_run_limits

So we upgraded our application to support HTTP2 and deployed it. below is the sample code.

```
const spdy = require('spdy');
const fs = require('fs');
const adminRouter = require("./routes/admin.router")

const PORT = 8080;
const CERT_DIR = `${__dirname}/cert`;
const useSSL = !!process.env.SSL;

const app = express();

app.use("/api", adminRouter)

function createServer() {
    if (!useSSL) {
        return app;
    }
    return spdy.createServer(
        {
            key: fs.readFileSync(`${CERT_DIR}/server.key`),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(`${CERT_DIR}/server.cert`),
            allowHTTP1: true
        },
        app
    );
}

const server = createServer();

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
    console.log(`SSL ${useSSL ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'}`);
});
```

We also enabled “**Use HTTP/2 end-to-end**” checkbox in cloud run service NETWORK Tab.
The moment we enabled this option we are getting this error “***upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: protocol error***”.

Can somebody throw some light on below questions,

1. Why do we get this error ? how do we resolve this ?
2. Is Cloud run a feasible service for our requirement of uploading huge files ?
3. If not what could be the alternate solution here? (remember we can’t use google cloud storage for business reasons) ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's not the right pattern! I recommend to generate a GCS signed URL and to let the browser uploaded the file directly on Cloud Storage. 5Gb is not designed for Cloud Run but for Cloud Storage https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

Comment: Thank you for recommending that solution @guillaumeblaquiere, unfortunately we are not supposed to use cloud storage. Additionally, we have Digital Ocean Space for uploading files.

Comment: Follow @guillaumeblaquiere advice. Besides the technical limitations and issues, uploading large files into Cloud Run requires memory to store the file. That will have an increased cost. Then you will pay again to transfer that data to another place (Cloud Run network egress). In other words, do not use Cloud Run as a file transfer device.

Comment: Thank you @guillaumeblaquiere and John , I followed your advise and started using digital ocean spaces ( storage) to upload my files from frontend using preSigned URLs generated at the backend. Now I am stuck at CORS error which is being thrown when I make a PUT request to preSignedURL. I have raised a ticket for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748318/cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing-with-put-request-to-digital-oc)